# Javascript Object, Dynamic data get last string after a point

Tags: javascript

I have an object with dynamic data. this returns a path, that can be different everytime.

for example I could have this inside my object, but it's dynamic so there is no static key name:

```
{
    data.name.data.name: tobi,
    data.name.data.text.data.lastname: rene,
    data.password.data.code: 231232
}
```

But I would like to have a function that only returns the last string after the last point of the key object.
The value should remain the same.

```
{
    name : tobi,
    lastname: rene
    code: 231232
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure those keys will be unique anyway, it's trivial using `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()`:

```
const input = {
    ["data.name.data.name"]: "tobi",
    ["data.name.data.text.data.lastname"]: "rene",
    ["data.password.data.code"]: 231232
};

const output = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(input).map(
        ([k, v])=>[k.replace(/.*\./, ''), v]
    )
);

console.log(output);
// { name: 'tobi', lastname: 'rene', code: 231232 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const object = {
      'data.name.data.first': 'tobi',
      'data.name.data.text.data.lastname': 'rene',
      'data.password.data.code': 231232
  }

  const modifyObject = () => {
    const output = Object.keys(object).map(item => {
      // get the key
      let key = item.split('.')
      key = key[key.length - 1]
      // get the value
      let value = object[item]
      // pair the key with the value
      return { [key]: value }
    })
    return output
  }

  console.log(modifyObject())
```

Output:

```
{
    first: "tobi"
    lastname: "rene"
    code: 231232
}
```